# Onclick event for a dynamically created html element in a for loop

Tags: jquery, html, json, tree

I have a json object with tree like data. I would like to display it on a UI interactively. On clicking a component its children should be displayed and so on. I wrote the following code

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>

            <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div>
              <ul id="result"></ul>

            </div>
            <script>
            var json_data = {
                "component": "A",
                "status": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "component": "AA",
                        "status": 0,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "component": "AAA",
                                "status": 0,
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "component": "AAB",
                                "status": 2,
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "component": "AB",
                        "status": 0,
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "component": "ABA",
                                "status": 0,
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "component": "ABB",
                                "status": 1,
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]

                    }
                ]
            };

            $(document).ready($(function(){
                var $result = $('#result');
                start(json_data )
                //Root Node display
                function start(obj)
                {

                    $('<li id="' + obj.component + '">').text(obj.component + '-'+obj.status).appendTo($result);
                    $("#"+obj.component).click(function(){
                        displaychildren(obj);
                    });

                }
                Display the children of an element on click by recursion
                 function displaychildren(node)
                {
                    $.each(node.children,function (i,v){
                            $('<li id="' + v.component + '">').text(v.component + '-'+v.status).appendTo($result);                                                    
                            if$("#"+v.component).click(function(){
                            alert("Problem is here");
                            displaychildren(v);
                            });

                        });                     
                }
                });
```

The problem I'm facing is the onclick of element in displaychildren function does not work. If the onclick condition is removed all the elements of all components are being dislayed. i want the children of the selected component only to be displayed. Does anyone know what is causing the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an error in your syntax:

```
if$("#"+v.component).click(function(){
```

should be (if you meant it to be this):

```
if($("#"+v.component).click(function(){
```

I'm guessing your code should read:

```
$("#"+v.component).click(function(){
                            alert("Problem is here");
                            displaychildren(v);
                            }
```

as the if() doesn't make much sense here around the click event.

Comment: Wow simply wow ........... it worked simply by removing the if ..... i thought all these days the error was in my object representation. Thanks a lot the dixon :)

Comment: No problem, sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes at a piece of code :)